# Why python send empty body with SMTP package?

Tags: python

I use [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) in order to send mails with python.

I have the following code:

```
import smtplib

# Credentials (if needed)
username = 'SECRET'
password = 'SECRET'

# The actual mail send
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo();
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)

# and in some function...

body = self.getVer()
body += "\n"
print body
server.sendmail(fromAddress, toAddresses, body)
```

The console print some lines (So `body` is not empty..), and I get the mail. But the mail is empty, and the body doesn't send.

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just a wild guess as I don't know smtplib: shouldn't you add a newline at the start of you body? Otherwise, the first lines up to the first empty line might be interpreted as headers?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer as you confirmed my "guess".

Comment: Could you try with "\r\n" instead of "\n" alone? According to RFC2821 `<LF>` only is _"a concession to
   non-conforming behavior on the part of some UNIX systems, [but] has proven
   to cause more interoperability problems than it solves"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add add a newline at the *start* of you body.

Otherwise, the first lines up to the first empty line are be interpreted as headers.

```
body = "\r\n"
body += self.getVer()
```

---

Please note, according to [RFC2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) section 4.1.1.4:

> The custom of accepting lines ending only in , as a concession to
>      non-conforming behavior on the part of some UNIX systems, has proven
>      to cause more interoperability problems than it solves, and SMTP
>      server systems MUST NOT do this, even in the name of improved
>      robustness.

As I understand it, the counterpoint client-side is that you MUST use `<CR><LF>` to denote end-of-line. Not `<LF>` alone.

---

In addition, as suggested by Simon Callan, you should definitively take a look at the [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) module.

---

Finally, you should swap `ehlo`/`starttls` lines in order to not send `EHLO` twice:

```
server.starttls()
server.ehlo();
```

Comment: As an additional step, I would advise using the 'email' module to construct the message that you are sending, as it will do all the important things like generating all the required headers.